# What are the politics of Steven Pinker?

Tags: united-states, political-theory

What are the politics of [Steven Pinker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Pinker)?

I have not heard or read a statement from him in which he describes the political theory to which he adheres.

Comment: Your post contains both a question and possible answers. I think they should be split (it's fine to answer your own question; others can provide additional answers).

Comment: @Alexei Just did, and added a comment in my question. Is it better like that? thx

Comment: Why should this person's political views be notable enough to ask a question about them here?  Near as I can tell, his profile is similar to Chomsky's.  Unlike Chomsky, that wiki page hardly has anything to say about politics.  Is he influential in political thinking, policy, government?

Comment: Is there any reason to suppose he is particularly political?  I mean, there lots of "celebrities". Some are obviously politically active, but for many it just isn't all that relevant.  They might vote in elections but they aren't active beyond that - just like most people.

Comment: @JamesK Thx for your comment. There is, see my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  It seems to confirm my suspicions.  He isn't particularly political.

Comment: I vaguely recall this has come up before on meta or at least one other Q that was closed. The politics or actors (or academics) are generally not on-topic unless they more clearly participate in the process. Him being on some Cato thing is kinda marginal for that. On a limited search I found an interview of him with Cato, but it's pretty far from political topics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPHd8GLuCgU

Comment: I can't answer but his ideological identity is clear to me. He is very much a classical liberal--one of those people who would like to rail against woke politics, consider themselves to be oppressed (part of the intellectual dark web), and promote and valorize the great Western tradition and defend it against its critics. So--socially liberal in the sense of having secular sensibilities but conservative in the sense of railing against radical non-sense ideas and societal excesses. Moderately economically liberal.

Comment: @Fizz Curious that you're not allowed to talk about ideology here? Everything is political and as long as they're being talked about politically I feel like it should be allowed

Answer (score 4):

Pinker is an academic and not a politician or a political theorist. As such, he is known less for an overall political worldview, and more for more specific insights he has championed in academia and popular thought. He is best known in political discussions for two books:

1. *The Blank Slate: The Modern Denial of Human Nature* (2002).

This book is cited mostly for the premise the genetic and congenital traits of a person are generally underestimated in importance in modern Western societies, while the importance of someone's environment and how they are raised is generally overestimated. The political left, in general, is very reluctant to admit that people can't be shaped more completely by parenting choices and the educational system.

2. *The Better Angels of Our Nature: Why Violence Has Declined* (2011).

The thesis of this book is that, empirically, society has become less violent over time, contrary to the paradigm of the 1960s to 1970s in anthropology from a far left leaning perspective that less advanced societies were peaceful and in harmony with nature.

This thesis also favors the position of Hobbs as a political theorist about the "state of nature" of humanity (in which life is "nasty, brutish, and short"), over political theories the paint a rosier picture of the default state of humanity without institutional and cultural interventions to prevent the state of nature from prevailing.

Both of these books undermine left leaning political excesses or misconceptions, in favor of facts. But, he is also making these observations from the perspective of the loyal to the left opposition who is secular, believes in science, and believes in progress in society, as exemplified by his more recent book:

*Enlightenment Now: The Case for Reason, Science, Humanism, and Progress* (February 13, 2018).

His most recent book underscores his approach to social science which holds certain values but also needs to be reality based and to deflate its own balloons and concepts when they turn out to not be supported by facts:

*Rationality: What It Is, Why It Seems Scarce, Why It Matters* (September 28, 2021).

Comment: thx for the response. It confirms my impression that he doesn't put forward his political stance. but I still maintain he has one (which is maybe social-liberalism)

Comment: @Starckman My point is mostly that his political stance isn't relevant to much more than my neighbor or my local middle school teacher's political stance. It doesn't add much insight to understanding what he has written, and isn't otherwise relevant. What is the point of trying to pigeon-hole him into somebody else's political ideology categories?

Comment: Depends on the point of view. I feel materialism (which is Pinker's philosophy) is defended **vocally** traditionnally by the left. More scarcely by free market theorists. See here https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/102913/are-there-liberal-economists-who-were-also-materialists

Comment: I think you are correct in the sense that it might be Pinker's own position. But on the other hand, I think the question of materialism being defended by which type of political theory is not as indifferent as you think; if we agree that materialism is important

Comment: @Starckman FWIW, your analysis at the link in Philosophy is deeply amiss in its premises. For example, most secular humanists favor some flavor of free market capitalism, and Pinker is not a socialist. Likewise the link lumps very different ideologies into "materialism" which strikes me as tone-deaf.

Comment: I did not say Pinker was a socialist.

Comment: "Both of these books undermine left leaning political excesses or misconceptions, in favor of facts." is an apt description: he does *not* undermine right leaning political excesses or misconceptions in favor of facts, so from a left leaning perspective he comes across as a right wing populist.

Comment: @Starckman You explicitly say Pinker is a socialist in the link to your question about materialism

Comment: @haxor789 It was in another context. In that context, Pinker is a socialist (which is a broad term which includes liberal socialism), as opposed to free market capitalists. In the context of this question, which concerns politics and thus should be more precise, I did not say, and do not wish to say, that Pinker is a socialist.

Comment: @Starckman What is "liberal socialism"? Like in some regard socialism is intrinsically "liberal", in the sense that it tries to liberate the individual and achieve the freedom and equality championed by liberalism, by going beyond classical liberalism and look at where it fails the working class. On the other hand if you ignore the grandstanding claims of classical liberalism and only focus on it's immediate goals of liberating the propertied commoners who demanded equality with the aristocracy but had not intention to extend that privilege to other groups, than it's in sharp opposition.

Comment: @haxor789 Sorry, I meant "social-liberalism"

Comment: "Like in some regard socialism is intrinsically "liberal", in the sense that it tries to liberate the individual and achieve the freedom and equality championed by liberalism, by going beyond classical liberalism and look at where it fails the working class." We could say that, in theory. But in practice it crushes both liberty and equality.

Comment: @Starckman So he has more of a laissez-faire attitude towards what people do in their spare time? And yeah in reality there's quite some discrepancy between socialist theory and what is actually done. To the point where people either argue the name doesn't fit leading to this "real existing socialism" which apparently was both used by opponents to mock the concept and by proponents to express real existing difficulties but their attempt to try or where if you go on to use that term you'd have to redefine it's meaning to reflect what can be seen rather than what is intended.

Comment: @haxor789 Who is "he"?

Comment: The one this question relates to: Pinker.

Comment: @haxor789 "So he has more of a laissez-faire attitude towards what people do in their spare time?" Well, precisely I don't think so; he defends many principles such as rationalism (his last book), but also science (in particular the fields of evolutionary psychology), humanism, etc., and often links them to a way to reach higher morality. Many libertarians, I think, may dislike him for these precise interventions on ethical questions

Comment: @Starckman "he defends many principles such as rationalism (his last book), but also science (in particular the fields of evolutionary psychology), humanism, etc., and often links them to a way to reach higher morality. Many libertarians, I think, may dislike him for these precise interventions on ethical questions" That all sounds perfectly libertarian-y to me. The presidents of the Libertarian Party quote Greek philosophy. How you don't think rationalist supremacy and linking things to higher morality is compatible with how the libertarian movement presents itself is beyond me.

Comment: @SimonRichter: yeah, being on a CATO thing is the apotheosis of "right wing populism". /s That that got 3 upvotes shows how clueless people are around here these days.

Answer (score 0):

It might either be social-liberalism (in the vein of Jeremy Bentham) or classical free market economic theory (also called libertarianism, or classical liberalism) (in the vein of Adam Smith, and Austrian economics).

He is an [Advisory board member](https://humanprogress.org/about/our-team/) for the project HumanProgress.org, which is a project of the Cato Institute. The Cato Institute is a libertarian (aka classical free market economic theory) thinktank, founded in 1977 by Ed Crane, Murray Rothbard, and Charles Koch.

On the other hand, he is a supporter of the American Democrats (see [here](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/15/us/steven-pinker-harvard.html)). He celebrated publicly on Twitter the victory of Joe Biden in the 2020 election.
I never heard Pinker calling for a lesser intervention of the state in the economy.

So I would say it is more social-liberalism (in the vein of Jeremy Bentham).

### In response to the comment below:

I think the phenomenon ("that there is a whole flank of people like that that have arose in recent years. They're mostly anti-woke leftists/liberals who couch themselves in grandiose statements about the Western tradition and how it's being threatened by radical ideologies nowadays from both the left and the right.") is real, and would say it has two sources:

_mainly, a rise of an opposition from people on the left, to what they call the "woke movement" (which is simply in continuation of the American "New Left" of the 1970's), that this more "traditional" left (affiliated either to social-democracy or social liberalism (aka center left/right), even communism and anarcho-communism) sees as irrational, anti-Enlightenment, etc. Among them, the center left/right group constitutes the most important bunch of people defending the "Western tradition" (aka "(Enlightenment) humanism"), in the US/UK and in Europe.

_an electoral and popular rise of the conservative-right (in the US and in Europe). They more sporadically emphasize some values of the "Western tradition" such as free-market capitalism, rationalism/science and individualism. Most of the time still, they speak about the defense of Judeo-Christianism and nationalism (which has little to do with "individualism", "rationalism", and "free-market capitalism", on the contrary).

These two movements coincide in time (after 2015, 2017), and follow similar but slightly different roads in the US/UK and in Europe (France).

**Descriptive analysis**

_In the US/UK:

The "traditional" left trend is represented by figures like Richard Dawkins, Steven Pinker, and the trios Boghossian-Lindsay-Pluckrose. Overall, they tend to be more self-identified as center-left and "humanism" than as libertarianism, same for the French left/right centrist network mentioned below.

The conservative-right trend is represented by networks such as the Daily Wire (Peterson, Shapiro), and PragerU.

_In Europe:

In Europe, like France, the "traditional" left opposition to the so-called "woke movement" comes from the left/right-centrist network "Franc-Tireur" (Enthoven, Fourest, etc.). Overall, they tend to be more self-identified as "universalist or humanist *républicains*", and tmk never as libertarians.

This opposition only recently started timidly to rise from the communists (Roussel, Ruffin) and the socialists (Cazeneuve), who re-emphasize their commitment to "(Enlightenment) humanism".

The (anti-woke) conservative-right (or far-right) rise is represented by the networks "Causeur" (Lévy, Finkielkraut) and "JDD" (Lejeune, D'Ornellas), and by Éric Zemmour.

Anti-woke opposition is also found in left-sovereigntist networks such as "Marianne" (Polony) and "Front Populaire" (Onfray). They are *rouge-brun* so it is difficult to classify them as either left or right (also they might overall more belong to the conservative-right, than to the left).

**Critical analysis**

But notice that the "traditional" left revaluation of the "Western tradition" has also a lot to see with an opposition to the conservative-right rise: Pinker wrote *Enlightenment Now* (2018) in response to Trump election, and the French center-left/right magazine "Franc-Tireur" defines itself as much anti-far-left as anti-far-right.

I would say, the Enlightenment values revaluation we find sporadically in the conservative-right trend (for them, it concerns free-market capitalism, rationalism/science, individualism) has two reasons. One is that it is used opportunistically as a pledge for credibility ("we are more rational and tempered than the woke movement we oppose to", "we are more respectful of individual liberty than the woke movement"). The bulk of their ideology remaining Judeo-Christianism and nationalism more than "(Enlightenment) humanism". The other is that the Western right is affiliated to liberal-conservatism (i.e. a liberalism on the economical and political side, therefore defense of economic and civil freedom, and a conservatism on the cultural side).

I don't think the "traditional" left trend would have been so vocal about the "Western tradition" without the appearance of the "woke movement" and the rise of the conservative-right, but see the former really as an opposition to the two latter. Otherwise, Dawkins would have continue to speak about religion in general, and Pinker about different topics related to language and science. The trios Boghossian-Lindsay-Pluckrose would not have existed, and the socialists and communists would have no need to vocally emphasize their fundamental philosophical commitment to the Enlightenment values.

In addition, this "anti-woke, pro-Western tradition movement" is supported by simultaneous significant geopolitical shifts, and global economy shifts.

Comment: You seem not to be aware that there is a whole flank of people like that that have arose in recent years. They're mostly anti-woke leftists/liberals who couch themselves in grandiose statements about the Western tradition and how it's being threatened by radical ideologies nowadays from both the left and the right. Read The Atlantic, Quillette, The Economist, follow David Brooks, Richard Dawkins, Jordan Peterson, J.K. Rowling

Comment: @user84614 Thank you. I thought thoroughly about your comment. My response to it is included in my answer. Any feedback on it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're missing the point that it's coming from one source and it's the reaction against radical ideologies on both the right and left during the era of social media. Yes there's types but only because it's interacting with existing right and left wing ideologies. The phenomenon itself is singular

Comment: @user84614 "it's coming from one source" which source?